# Git pull successfully but not shown in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, pull

I have a project imported from git repository to eclipse. The thing is, when others made changes from their parts (kind of structure changes of the package and class folder structure), I used git pull and it worked properly.

The thing is, the change is shown in my local repository but not in eclipse. I don't how to make eclipse update.

Even though i delete the project from eclipse and reimport again but still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to import these new changes into your eclipse workspace after git pull.

In **Git Repositories** view go to the repository expand the the repository and right click on **Working Directory** then select **Import projects..** then a wizard will appear follow the instruction.